# How to calculate balance of AVL-Tree node recursively and in a single function? (Python)

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

First question here so if I omit something important please do tell me.
I have a balanced AVL tree and I need to create a function that can calculate the balance of a single given node. This needs to happen in a single function and **recursively**. (This is in Python, by the way)

I have also included the instantiation method for the Node class, so that you can see the attributes of the nodes.
So far, I have come up with this, and, while it works, it still does not fulfill the criteria:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, value, root): 
        self.value = value # Node value
        self.left = None # Left child
        self.right = None # Right child
        self.root = root # Stores the original root of the tree

    def getBalance(self, node):
        return self.getTreeHeight(node.right)-self.getTreeHeight(node.left)
        
    def getTreeHeight(self, rootnode):
        if rootnode == None:
            return -1
        else: 
            return max(self.getTreeHeight(rootnode.left), self.getTreeHeight(rootnode.right)) + 1
```

Any tips would be appreciated.
All I need is a nudge in the right direction, because honestly, I'm a bit stumped.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The notion of balance is not inductive: when you know the balance of the two children of a node, you cannot derive from that information what the balance is of the node itself. So if the solution needs to use recursion, that recursion will have to be about more than just the balance. You cannot hope to create a `getBalance` that can do the job by just calling itself recursively. It will either need to return more than just the balance (like also the heights), or depend on another function that will use recursion.

Comment: Why do your methods require a `node` argument? Surely you would call these methods *on the nodes* you want them to give info about, so why you require the argument still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some general comments on your implementation:

- It is unusual to provide each node with a pointer to the root of the tree. This is very unpractical if you decide to add a new node at the top of the tree, making the current root a child of the new node. Then you would have to visit *every* node to update the reference to the root.
- The two methods take a node as argument, but that is a pity, as `self` is already a node, and so *that* node could be the subject of the operation. This would need a minor change in `getTreeHeight`, as there you currently allow the argument to be `None`.  But in the end it is better to have these methods work without argument (except `self`).

Now to the question. It is not possible to write a `getBalance` method that only calls itself and does not pass or return any extra information. This is because the notion of balance is not inductive: if you know the balance of the children of a given node, then this information is of no use to determine the balance of the node itself. So you need somehow to pass on some extra information.

One way to do this, is to add an optional parameter to `getBalance` which will indicate whether the function was called recursively or not. If recursively, it could return the height, if not, the balance. That way you actually merge the two functions you already wrote:

```
def getBalance(self, recurring=False):
    left = self.left.getBalance(True) if self.left else 0
    right = self.right.getBalance(True) if self.right else 0
    return max(left, right) + 1 if recurring else right - left
```

Call as:

```
node = root.left.right.right  # get a reference to some node in your tree
balance = node.getBalance()  # get the balance of that node (no argument!)
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, this was helpful! Regarding the nodes being parameters, which is indeed unnecessary, I unfortunately received a partly written code and was not allowed to change it, so the nodes as parameters had to stay, some other methods were called like this.